# How do I capture the output of a Perl program so I can mail it?

Tags: perl

I want to send the output of a Perl file in the body of the mail. Can some one let me know how I can capture the output of the Perl which prints something on the cmd to a variable?

I am running a Perl script from a command prompt and I get the output on the command prompt itself. I want to print the output on the command prompt to the body of an email. I have the function which can send the email but don't know how to capture that output. I hope its bit clear now.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit?  Do you want the output of the script in a variable within the script itself, in a variable in a different script that's executing the first script, or somewhere else?  Is the script itself sending the email?

Comment: In a perl variable or in a shell variable or something else?  How are you sending the email?

Comment: There are many ways to capture the output of a program in a Perl program:  [Interact with the system when Perl isn’t enough](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/04/when-perl-isnt-enough/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending the email from a perl script and want to include the body of another perl script, do:

```
use IPC::System::Simple 'capturex';
my $body = capturex( 'perl', '/path/to/your/script' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
my_variable=$(perl myperl.pl)
```

Example:

```
$ cat myperl.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
print "stackoverflow\n";
$ my_variable=$(perl myperl.pl)
$ echo $my_variable
stackoverflow
$
```